# Ayuda con expresión regular para un pequeño compilador en C++

Tags: c++, regex

apenas me inicio en esto de expresiones regulares porque normalmente no he tenido la necesidad de salir mas allá de un email, username, password, etcétera, pero se me ha dado la tarea de crear una validación para un pequeño "compilador" y la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo es creando expresiones regulares. El formato del programa es este:

Inicio.

var n1, n2, n3, n4=TD$

Iden:Iden (op) Iden$

Fin.

Iden son caracteres alfanumericos [:alnum:] segun la sintaxis de Google

TD puede ser ent o real

n* tambien son caracteres alfanumericos y puede haber N de ellos

$ se usa como fin de linea, y (op) puede ser +,/,*,- pero se reemplaza por =suma=,=resta=,=multiplicacion=,=division= para evitar problemas con las expresiones regulares, al igual que $ se cambia por .fin. para evitar problemas

He armado una pequeña expresion regular pero cuando la pruebo en C++ la funcion regex_match me retorna 0, es decir, false. Esta es mi expresión:

`^Inicio.var[:alnum:]![[,[:alnum:]]?[,[:alnum:]]]=(ent|real).fin.[:alnum:]:[:alnum:](=suma=,=resta=,=producto=,=division=)[:alnum:].fin.Fin.$`

Y aqui esta el codigo que me retorna 0:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        string code = "Inicio.vart1,t2,t3=ent.fin.t1=t2=suma=t3.fin.Fin.";
        string expresion = "^Inicio.var[:alnum:]![[,[:alnum:]]?[,[:alnum:]]]=(ent|real).fin.[:alnum:]:[:alnum:](=suma=,=resta=,=producto=,=division=)[:alnum:].fin.Fin.$";
        smatch sm;
        cout << regex_match(code, sm, regex(expresion));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolver, dejo aqui la expresion regular utilizada:

```
^Inicio.var(\w|\w,).*=(ent|real)\$(\w+).*:(\w+).*(\*|\+|-|/)(\w+).*\$Fin.$
```

Probé con este código:

```
Inicio.varn,nh,ni,nuy=ent$n:n+nh$Fin.
```